# Loop over each group and subtract their value

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame (id= c(1,1,1,2,2), time = c(13,14,17,17,17))

  id time
1  1   13
2  1   14
3  1   17
4  2   17
5  2   17
```

and I wish to go over on each id and subtract the next time and the previous time. So, My ideal output will be:

```
#output 
   id time  diff
1  1   13    0
2  1   14    1
3  1   17    3
4  2   17    0
5  2   17    0
```

What is the most efficient way for that?

Comment: Thanks @ZheyuanLi, worked perfectly. please consider writing your comment as am answer below, then I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R did not come up in my search. Do I need to delete this question?

Comment: @MFR Either way. You can just leave it and if other people agree it's a dupe it will be closed. But that may actually count towards a question ban, so yea you might want to delete it come to think of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Please close it now.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I just remembered there was a trending question on Meta yesterday that indicated closed questions count towards a ban. So it may negatively affect him if it's closed.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi ok. just wanted to mention that. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank so Zheyuan Li.

This is a great solution:

```
df$diff <- with(df, ave(time, id, FUN = function (x) c(0, diff(x))))
```